# Django similar queryset optimization

Tags: python, django

I am making a filmography website.
However, I am having a hard time optimizing the queryset in the detailview.

```
class Actor(model.Models):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()

class Movie(model.Models):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    movie_title = models.CharField()
    actor = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name='relations')

class ActorView(DetailView):
    model = Actor
    context_object_name = 'actor'
    template_name = 'actor.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['movies'] = self.object.relations.all()
        return context


<div>
   {{ actor.name }}
   {% for movie in movies %}
       {{ movie.movie_title }}
       {% for actor_info in movie.actor.all %}
       {{ actor.name }}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I checked the sql tap in the django debug console.

```
   {% for actor_info in movie.actor.all %}
   {{ actor.name }}
   {% endfor %}
```

Similar queries are being executed repeatedly in the code above.
And data connection and query execution time are also very slow.
How can I optimize this part in the view or model?

Comment: please what exactly is your goal and what do you mean by optimize?

Comment: @kwamito  ttfb time is getting longer, so optimizing the query set.  (It reduces the repetition of similar queries and shortens the query execution time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed this up using [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

So in your view, change this line from

```py
context['movies'] = self.object.relations.all()
```

to

```py
context['movies'] = self.object.relations.all().prefetch_related("actor")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django, select_related and prefetch_related are designed to stop the deluge of database queries that are caused by accessing related objects as mentioned

So for `ForeignKey`  and `OneToOneField` relations you can use `select_related` and for `ManyToManyField` you can use `prefetch_related` which.

[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) says

> Prefetch related returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

> This has a similar purpose to select_related, in that both are designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different.

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.

```
class ActorView(DetailView):
    model = Actor
    context_object_name = 'actor'
    template_name = 'actor.html'

    # Overide the get_object method and set prefetch_related
    def get_object(self, queryset):
        return super().get_object(queryset).prefetch_related("movies")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['movies'] = self.get_object().relations.all()
        return context
```